# How can I create a different realm instance at the same time for ui thread?

Tags: android, realm, realm-list, realmrecyclerviewadapter

I have multiple fragments which are inside activities. I have called myAdapter in fragment `onActivityCreate` method.

I have read too many articles for realm performance improvements, adapter management, realm usage. I open the realm in resume and close it in pause. But sometimes my realm adapter has shown empty.When I've deleted `closeRealm` method, my adapter was running normally.

My error is because of overlapping openRealm and closeRealm from different adapters.

First adapter is opening -> openRealm--onCreate *(time : 21:15)* closing->closeRealm--onPause *(time : 21:30:12)*

Second adapter is opening -> openRealm--onCreate *(time: 21:30:23)* :: Above adapter is closing this realm

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#configuring-a-realm : It is important to note that Realm instances are thread singletons, meaning that the static constructor will return the same instance in response to all calls from a given thread.

I can manage realm for realm thread but can't manage ui thread. How can I create a different realm instance at the same time for ui thread? Please help me.

> Realm adapter:

```
abstract class MyRealmRecyclerViewAdapter<T extends MyModel, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
        extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<MyModel, VH> {

    protected Context context;
    private String TAG = MyRealmRecyclerViewAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    protected Realm realm;

    MyRealmRecyclerViewAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<T> data, Realm realm) {

        super((OrderedRealmCollection<MyModel>) data, true, true);

        if (data != null && !data.isManaged()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Only use this adapter with managed RealmCollection, " +
                    "for un-managed lists you can just use the BaseRecyclerViewAdapter");
        }

        setRealm(realm);
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

}
```

> My fragment:

```
    public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        private boolean isRealmAssignee = false;
        private Realm realm;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onActivityCreated(bundle);

            Mylog.i(TAG, " onActivityCreated");
             try {
                myAdapter = new MyRealmRecyclerViewAdapter<>(this,
                        new MyQueries().getAllItems(getRealm()),getRealm());

                recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Mylog.printStackTrace(TAG + " initializeListAdapter error", e);
            }
        }

      @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

            Mylog.i(TAG, " onResume");

            setRealm();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {

            super.onPause();

            Mylog.i(TAG, " onPause");
            closeRealm();
        }

        public void setRealm() {

            if (!isRealmAssignee && !RealmManager.checkRealm(realm)) {
                this.realm = RealmManager.open();
                isRealmAssignee = true;
            }
        }

        public Realm getRealm() {

            if (!RealmManager.checkRealm(realm)) {

                isRealmAssignee = false;
                setRealm();
            }

            return realm;
        }

        public void closeRealm() {

            RealmManager.close(realm);
            isRealmAssignee = false;
        }
```

> RealmManager:

```
public class RealmManager {

    public synchronized static Realm open() {

        return Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    public synchronized static void close(Realm mRealm) {

        if (checkRealm(mRealm)) {
            mRealm.close();
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkRealm(Realm realm) {
        return realm != null && !realm.isClosed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what articles you were reading on Realm performance, but https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle would have been sufficient.

Comment: please see my edited question and share example which is usage realm for multiple adapters

Comment: For your use-case, i'd recommend this approach: https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/tree/831ab834ed304385143f0918d7694abc42421c7a/monarchy-example/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/monarchyexample/features/managed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question would be to use a `ThreadLocal<Realm>`.

```
private final ThreadLocal<Realm> localRealms = new ThreadLocal<>();

/**
 * Opens a reference-counted local Realm instance.
 *
 * @return the open Realm instance
 */
public Realm openLocalInstance() {
    checkDefaultConfiguration();
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // <-- this could use input RealmConfiguration
    Realm localRealm = localRealms.get();
    if(localRealm == null || localRealm.isClosed()) {
        localRealms.set(realm);
    }
    return realm;
}

public Realm getLocalInstance() {
    Realm realm = localRealms.get();
    if(realm == null || realm.isClosed()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "No open Realms were found on this thread.");
    }
    return realm;
}

public void closeLocalInstance() {
    checkDefaultConfiguration();
    Realm realm = localRealms.get();
    if(realm == null || realm.isClosed()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Cannot close a Realm that is not open.");
    }
    realm.close();
    // noinspection ConstantConditions
    if(Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration()) <= 0) {
        localRealms.set(null);
    }
}
```

And then you could use `realmManager.openLocalInstance()` and `realmManager.closeLocalInstance()` from `onCreateView`/`onDestroyView` to manage the lifecycle, while use `realmManager.getLocalInstance()` elsewhere on the given thread.

---

But it might just be easier to use `findAllManaged*` in my library named [Monarchy](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/) which handles automatic Realm lifecycle management.

Comment: Very thanks. What should I do that closeThisRealm(realm) and how can I find inside localRealms

Comment: AFAIK if you call `getInstance` twice then `realm1 == realm2`, and there's a reference counter that is increased. So no need to close specific instances of Realm, only number of times matters (and it occurs on the current thread, of course)

Comment: at openLocalInstance 4.line :  `if(localRealm != null && !localRealm.isClosed()) {localRealms.set(realm);}`
It does not have to be this way otherwise it is true?

Comment: It's just there for safety but generally. Generally it'll be `localRealm == null` if you use it when the Realm was closed and then you call `open`.